# Tool/Plugin for checking UI Specifications

Tags: html, search, testing

Do you know any good way to check the actual Web element's specification, like check the font size, pixel spacing between elements, colors of text, spacing on a block? Maybe there is a tool or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Page Ruler plugin for Chrome is what I was looking for